# ¿Cómo definir en una query de SPARQL un data type?

Tags: sql, owl

Estoy trabajando con ontologías OWL, y estoy realizando querys en ella desde NetBeans.

Mi query es:

```
"PREFIX a: <http://www.owl-ontologies.com/Indoor.owl#> "  
+ "SELECT ?X "  
+ "WHERE { ?X a:hasDay a:" + day + " . "  
+ " ?X a:hasRoom a:" + room + " . "  
+ " ?X a:hasStartTime a:" + startTime +" }";
```

Al momento de consultar la query, la consola me arroja:

> ```
> Undefined object property used in query:
> http://www.owl-ontologies.com/Indoor.owl#hasStartTime
> ```

Pero `hasStartTime` no es un *object property*, es un data type (un int).

¿Cómo hago para que interprete a `hasStartTime` como un dataType?